# avroserializer declarion in spring properties

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to use an avroserializer for value serialization in a kafka publisher. This is the entry I added in my application properties:

```
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.class
```

I am getting the below exception.Please help me what to change here.

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-06-22 00:25:15.926 ERROR 25080 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer' to java.lang.Class<?>:

    Property: spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer
    Value: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.class
    Origin: class path resource [application.properties] - 22:40
    Reason: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Class<?>]

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

I tried with this option also:

```
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
```

Comment: The error message suggests that your property end with `.class` which isn’t needed and doesn’t match your description. Can you confirm the exact value in your `application.properties` file?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson thats a good catch, actually I tried with both the entries:

Comment: Another thing to check is that the class and everything that it depends upon are on the classpath. Does you application have a dependency on `io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer`?

Comment: I don't think you get the same error with the other entry, so please edit your question to reflect those change